# ID fields not auto filled for table with multiple associations (CakePHP)

Tags: database, cakephp, model, associations, relationship

I'm working on a customer database. For larger business customers the relationships get a little complicated. It's almost working but one ID field is not being automatically filled.

I have 3 models, Customer, CustomerAddress and CustomerContact. A customer can have many addresses, and many contacts, but the contacts are also based at one address so an address has many contacts.

```
Database:
customer has id
customer_addresses has customer_id
customer_contacts has customer_id, customer_address_id

Models:
class Customer extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'CustomerContact',
        'CustomerAddress',
    );

    ....
}

class CustomerAddress extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array( 
        'Customer',
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'CustomerContact',        
    );

    ....
}

class CustomerContact extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array( 
        'Customer',
        'CustomerAddress',
    );

    ....
}
```

I have one form that adds fields for all 3 models, and I'm calling '$this->Customer-saveAll' in the controller. It saves everything just fine, but doesn't fill in the 'customer_address_id' field in the 'customer_contacts' table.

I've tried changing the relationship in contacts to belongs to address, I've tried renaming the field to customer_addresses_id (made it pleural) just incase it was a quirk with Cake's internal naming, but it still doesn't fill the address ID field.

My workaround is to update the contact after the saveAll command in the controller, since the address has it's id set at this point:

```
$this->CustomerContact->saveField( 'customer_address_id', $this->CustomerAddress->id);
```

This is my first project with Cake and it seems really good at doing this stuff by itself, so I'm wondering if I've got something wrong somewhere.

TIA!

## EDIT:

After going through the associations again, I changed the association on CustomerContact from hasOne to belongsTo CustomerAddress because I realised I got it wrong.

I tried 2 different ways of submitting the data:

```
'Customer' => .... data ....
'CustomerAddress' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'CustomerContact' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                .... data ....
            )
        ),
        .... data ....
    )
)
```

This sets the customer_address_id field on the contact, but not customer_id.

```
'Customer' => .... data ....
'CustomerAddress' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        .... data ....
    )
),
'CustomerContact' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        .... data ....
    )
)
```

This sets the customer_id but not the customer_address_id.

Comment: You kind of lost me in the way so I'm not sure this is exactly what happens but I think you're trying to save a main model id together with the child model that references the same main model. If that's the case, save the main model in your code and then add the returned id to all child references. That's when save all will work.

Comment: I think I also lost myself. Taking a step back, I posted a more concise question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580876/how-to-correctly-set-associations-between-3-models-cakephp