# How to correctly set multiple associations between 3 models (CakePHP)

Tags: database, cakephp, model, associations

So I'm trying to work this out last night, and after thinking myself around in circles a few times decided I need some help. I did post a question about an ID field not being filled in but it got too long winded and confusing, and I realised the problem was probably based on the associations.

I'm working on a customer database. For larger business customers the relationships get a little complicated. I have 3 models, Customer, CustomerAddress and CustomerContact. A customer can have many addresses, and many contacts, but the contacts are also based at one address so an address has many contacts.

The end result I'm trying to achieve is to be able to search the data both ways, e.g.

```
Customer -> Address 1 -> Contact 1, Contact 2, Contact 3, etc....
            Address 2 -> Contact ... ... ...
            ....
```

Or....

```
Customer -> Contact 1 -> Address
            Contact 2 -> Address
            ....
```

The issue I'm having is that an Address must `hasMany` contacts and a contact must `hasOne` address, but these 2 relationships conflict because the other side should `belongsTo` and it doesn't.

Comment: At a minimum: in the Contact table, store the primary key of the Address table. In the Address table, store the primary key of the Customer table. The Cakephp use of _hasOne_ term complicates analysis. Your contact _belongsTo_ an address. FYI: hasOne is not as common as belongsTo in database schemes.

Comment: Yeah I currently have it working like that, as in the first example I posted. The problem is I can't search the contacts without looking up all the addresses too.

Comment: The relationships don't have to be reciprocal. Why can't you use Address hasMany Contacts?

Comment: If address hasMany contacts, then contacts must belongTo address. In that case I'm not sure how I can do a find that will return results like in my second example?

Answer (score 0):

Such coincidence. Just learnt this last week!
As far as I can see, here is a basic relation layout

Customer hasMany Address
Address belongsTo Customer

Address hasMany Contact
Contact belongsTo Address

Now this covers the basic model of the first case you want to achieve. To search for Contact from Customer via Address.

As for the second case. Querying from the contact towards the Customer would be mighty expensive so, my suggestion is

Create a relation:

Customer hasMany Address and *build a Model on top of this*. This kind of relation is called hasMany through where two Models have a hasMany relation but have more information riding on top of the relation. For example:

Group hasAndBelongsToMany User
User hasAndBelongsToMany Group

This requires a new table groups_users. Also, each group can have multiple admin. Assuming we are following all 2.x conventions. Cake doesn't allow extra columns in this table. So if this relation group_users is treated as a Model. We can add as much extra columns in it as we want.

Relation becomes
GroupUser belongsTo array('User', 'Group');
User hasmany GroupUser
Group hasmany GroupUser

In your case create the relation: Customer hasMany Address to a Model. Lets call is CustomerAddress.

Then CustomerAddress hasMany Contact and Contact belongsTo CustomerAddress.

hope this helps!